# No puedo instalar algunos programas en linux mint - http://mirror.upb.edu.co/ubuntu

Tags: linux, instalacion, linux-mint

Al intentar instalar desde la consola o desde el instalador de paquetes algunos programas obtengo:

Err:1 http://mirror.upb.edu.co/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libapache-pom-java all 18-1
  No se puede iniciar la conexión a mirror.upb.edu.co:80 (2801:190:0:a010:0:200:50c8:7b09). - connect (101: La red es inaccesible) No se pudo conectar a mirror.upb.edu.co:80 (200.3.145.185), caducó el tiempo para conexión
Err:2 http://mirror.upb.edu.co/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libatinject-jsr330-api-java all 1.0+ds1-5
  No se puede iniciar la conexión a mirror.upb.edu.co:80 (2801:190:0:a010:0:200:50c8:7b09). - connect (101: La red es inaccesible)

Sugiere lo siguiente:

No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?

Ejecuto sudo apt-get update y sudo apt install maven --fix-missing que era lo que estaba intentado instalar, pero obtengo los mismos errores.

Tambien me ha pasado cuando intento instalar Zoom. En el instalador de paquetes aparece Falló al descargar los archivos de paquetes:

Failed to fetch http://mirror.upb.edu.co/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb-xtest0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to mirror.upb.edu.co:80 (2801:190:0:a010:0:200:50c8:7b09). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirror.upb.edu.co:80 (200.3.145.185), connection timed out

Por favor ayúdenme a solucionarlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En esta página encontré la solución:
https://ubuntu.dokry.com/120/como-soluciono-el-error-error-al-descargar-los-archivos-del-paquete.html

Allí decía:
Presione **Alt + F2** y escriba **software-properties-gtk**.
Cuando haces eso te sale la siguiente pantalla y en donde sale **Base(bionic)** yo tenia la que decia mirror.upb.edu.co

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego lo remplacé por mirror.unimagdalena.edu.co que era otra opción para mi país Colombia. Si no es tu caso, escoje **un servidor de tu país o cercano a este**. Aplica los cambios y ya puedes probar nuevamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Solo se escribe `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` y es para raparar los posibles errores en la base de datos de cambios de apt